# first scrum case study

Tags: agile, scrum

I was wondering if anyone knows where can I find scrum's first case study? I need it as a reference. I couldn't find anything relating to it.

It has to be the first one that Jeff Sutherland used to proof scrum worked as a development methodology.

Thank you.

Comment: If I were in you, rather than asking to StackOverflow, I would ask directly to Jeff Sutherland (@jeffsutherland) on Twitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a full chapter or two of information about the first Scrum case studies in the book [Agile Software Development with Scrum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130676349) by Ken Schwaber and Mike Beedle.  I realize it is a book, but that is where you are going to want to start.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may want the January 1986 *Harvard Business Review* article *"The New New Product Development Game",* by Hirotaka Takeuchi and Ikujiro Nonaka that has case studies.

> In today's fast-paced, fiercely competitive world of commercial new
>   product development, speed and flexibility are essential. Companies
>   are increasingly realizing that the old, sequential approach to
>   developing new products simply won't get the job done. Instead, com-
>   panies in Japan and the United States are using a holistic method—as
>   in rugby, the ball gets passed within the team as it moves as a unit
>   up the field. This holistic approach has six characteris- tics:
>   built-in instability, self-organizing project teams, overlapping
>   development phases, "multilearning," subtle control, and
>   organizational transfer of learning. The six pieces fit together like
>   a jigsaw puzzle, forming a fast and flexible process for new product
>   development, fust as im- portant, the new approach can act as a change
>   agent: it is a vehicle for introducing creative, market-driven ideas
>   and processes into an old, rigid organization.

It has a section titled *Moving the scrum downfield*.  There is a [pdf available](http://www.sao.corvallis.or.us/drupal/files/The%20New%20New%20Product%20Development%20Game.pdf).

The first published work by Sutherland on SCRUM appears to be from the mid 90s.